# getElementbyID returns Null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a javascript call, which onclick will create a new window of a specific part of the page, and print it.

To do this, I'm modifying someone else's SF answer, that was trying to do something similar

```
<div class="patienspecials clearfix" id="print_div1">
    <h1>Bla bla bla</h1> 
    <a href="#" onclick="printInfo(print_div1)"><img 
        class="alignnone size-full wp-image-6196" alt="print-icon" 
        src="#" width="92" height="28" /></a>
</div>
```

I'm trying pass the div print_div1 as an argument to this function --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printInfo(ele) {
    var openWindow = window.open("", "title", "attributes");
    openWindow.document.write(document.getElementById(ele));
    openWindow.document.close();
    openWindow.focus();
    openWindow.print();
    openWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

However, when I run the script, the print command simply creates a new page with the text "null".

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with getElementById, do you guys have any ideas on how to make this work? Still a noob and would appreciate the help!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printInfo(print_div1)` will pass the element with an ID of `print_div1`, not pass the string `'print_div1'`.

Just update your JavaScript to use the element being passed, instead of trying to use it as a string ID to query for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printInfo(ele) {
    var openWindow = window.open("", "title", "attributes");
    //no longer need to select the element by ID, just use it
    openWindow.document.write(ele);
    openWindow.document.close();
    openWindow.focus();
    openWindow.print();
    openWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

---

If you really wanted to use `document.getElementById()` for some reason, just make sure to quote the string id in your inline event:

```
<div class="patienspecials clearfix" id="print_div1">
    <h1>Bla bla bla</h1> 
    <!-- Notice the quotes around 'print_div1' -->
    <a href="#" onclick="printInfo('print_div1')"><img 
        class="alignnone size-full wp-image-6196" alt="print-icon" 
        src="#" width="92" height="28" /></a>
</div>
```

Changing either one (but not both) should work fine. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its be because you are passing an undefined variable `print_div1` instead of a string. use:

`<a onclick="printInfo('print_div1')">...</a>`

Comment: The variable is defined, the global context has a property named for each element with an ID that refers to the respective element.